# Override Directories for Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have the following structure in my Nuxt application:

```
/nuxtapp
/nuxtapp/src/
/nuxtapp/src/config
/nuxtapp/src/static
/nuxtapp/src/organizations
/nuxtapp/src/organizations/org1/config
/nuxtapp/src/organizations/org1/static
```

The other usual directories you usually see in Nuxt also exist.

What I want to try to figure out is this idea of specifying somewhere in my application that I want to use "org1", in which case, the following code would automatically grab the `org.json` that I have in the `org1` folder instead of the default one:

```
<script>
  import orgConfig from '~/config/org.json'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        orgConfig: orgConfig
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would like to accomplish the same thing within my templates if I were to reference an image like so:

```
<img src="/icon.png" alt="Icon" width="100" height="100">
```

In which case it would automatically search to see if the `org1/static` folder has `icon.png`, otherwise, it will use the default.

Comment: So do you simply want to change your project root or are you trying to emulate Node's require() pattern of checking a ruleset and hierarchy of dependency paths?

Comment: The second one.
I've already changed my source directory using `srcDir` option.